# simple form submission and confirmation page without database using HTML/PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I am creating a simple solution for printing a stock details in php without a Database. I have a page with forms, so user can enter product quantity. Once submit the form, we can get a confirmation page (I use this page for printing purpose) where it displays all active items and quantity. If the user doesn't enter a value for any of the Input field in the form, the particular item name and quantity field will not be visible on confirmation page. Please find the images below for more details. Please help. Thanks

***Page with actual form and user enter values for all fields***
[image]

***Confirmation Page with all field with values***
[image]

***Page with actual form and user enter values for only two fields***
[image]

***Confirmation page shows only chosen fields like below***
[image]

***Here is the code - StockForm.php***

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Stockr Form</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Stock Form</h1>
<form action="confirmation.php" method="post">
  <p> Enter Total No. of  iPad Air2:
    <input type="text" name="ipadair2" size="30">
  </p>
  <p> Enter Total No. of iPhone6:
    <input type="text" name="iphone6" size="30">
  </p>
  <p> Enter Total No. of iMac:
    <input type="text" name="imac" size="30">
  </p>
  <p>
    <button type="submit">Generate Report</button>
  </p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

***Here is the code - Confirmation.php***

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Confirmation Page</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
    //Get the input.
    $ipadair2 = $_POST['ipadair2'];
    $iphone6 = $_POST['iphone6'];
 $imac = $_POST['imac'];
    //Compute totals.
    
    $stock_total = $ipadair2 + $iphone6 + $imac;
    //Output totals.
    ?>
<p>Stock Confirmation.</p>
<table width="559" border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <th width="407">Product</th>
    <th width="126">Quantity</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>iPad Air2</td>
    <td><?php print $ipadair2; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>iPhone6</td>
    <td><?php print $iphone6; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>iMac</td>
    <td><?php print $imac; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td >Total Items</td>
    <td width="126"><?php print $stock_total; ?></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, and your question is?

Comment: @Marco Thank you. If the user is not entering values for any item (Eg: iphone 6 input field), the confirmation page shouldn't include that name iPhone6 and its entire row (Currently it is static). Please check the images I provided "Page with actual form and user enter values for only two fields" if you don't mind.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

(I'll do it for one var)
First, check that the var exist

```
if(isset($_POST['ipadair2']) && is_numeric($_POST['ipadair2'])){
 $ipadair2 = $_POST['ipadair2'];
} else {
 $ipadair2 = 0;
}
```

Then, instead of:

```
<tr>
    <td>iPad Air2</td>
    <td><?php print $ipadair2; ?></td>
  </tr>
```

You can do something like:

```
if($ipadair2 > 0){
?>
<tr>
    <td>iPad Air2</td>
    <td><?php print $ipadair2; ?></td>
  </tr>
<?php
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can just get the inputs in array and check in confirmation.php page.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Stock Form</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Stock Form</h1>
<form action="confirmation.php" method="post">
  <p> Enter Total No. of  iPad Air2:
    <input type="text" name="Stock[ipadair2]" size="30">
  </p>
  <p> Enter Total No. of iPhone6:
    <input type="text" name="Stock[iphone6]" size="30">
  </p>
  <p> Enter Total No. of iMac:
    <input type="text" name="Stock[imac]" size="30">
  </p>
  <p>
    <button type="submit">Generate Report</button>
  </p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

confirmation.php

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Confirmation Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        //Get the input.
        if (isset($_POST['Stock'])) {
            $stockData = $_POST['Stock'];
        }
        ?>
        <p>Stock Confirmation.</p>
        <table width="559" border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <th width="407">Product</th>
                <th width="126">Quantity</th>
            </tr>
            <?php
            $stock_total = 0;
            foreach ($stockData as $key => $value) {
                ?>
                <?php
                $stock_total = $stock_total + $value;
                if (!empty($value)) {
                    ?>
                    <tr> 
                        <td><?php echo $key; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $value; ?></td>
                    </tr>
            <?php } 
            } ?>

            <tr>
                <td >Total Items</td>
                <td width="126"><?php print $stock_total; ?></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can I have an email option? I am little confused about sending through mail.php